# How to get the value of product description from purchase.order

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I want to add a "designation" field in the "stock.quant.tree" view that displays the description of each product in stock. I have already added the field in the tree but I am stuck how I get the value of the description product of the model "purchase.order" to "stock.quant" Any idea for help please?

[image]

stock_quant_tree_designation.xml

```
<data>

<record id="stock_quant_tree_designation" model="ir.ui.view">

        <field name="name">stock.quant.tree.designation</field>

        <field name="model">stock.quant</field>

        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_stock_quant_tree"/>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='qty']" position="after">

                        <field name="designation2"/>

            </xpath>

        </field>

    </record>

</data>
```

stock.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv 
from openerp import tools , api
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools.translate import _
class StockQuantTreeDesignation(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'stock.quant'
_columns = {
'designation2': fields.char(string="Désignation", required=True, select=True),
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You already have `product_id` field in `stock.quant`, you can make `designation2` related to `product_id`.

```
designation2 = fields.Char(related='product_id.name')
```

To add a relation between `purchase.order` and  `stock.quant` you can use a compute field that search for `move_id` from `quant_ids` field to access the `picking_id` which store the `purchase.order` name (unique) in`origin` field.

```
# coding: utf8
from openerp import models, fields, api


class StockQuant(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.quant"

    purchase_id = fields.Many2one("purchase.order", string="Purchase Order", compute="_get_purchase_order")

    @api.multi
    def _get_purchase_order(self):
        for record in self:
            # Search for one move_id to get stock_picking reference
            self.env.cr.execute("SELECT move_id FROM stock_quant_move_rel WHERE quant_id=%s LIMIT 1", (record.id,))
            (move_id, ) = self.env.cr.fetchone()
            move = self.env["stock.move"].browse(move_id)
            # Use stock_picking to get purchase_order reference using `origin` which is unique
            po = self.env["purchase.order"].search([("name", '=', move.picking_id.origin)])
            record.purchase_id = po.id
```

Comment: i want to get  the field `name` from `purchase order` and  the only way i know it is to relate `purchase.order` with `stock.quant` using `purchase_id` that's why i use it but if there is another way to relate the two models its ok

Comment: Thanks but it shows error : `ValueError: "ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne \xab designation2 \xbb
DETAIL:  La ligne en \xe9chec contient (2, PO00001, 2018-07-26 10:56:05.683, null, 1, 6, 1, null, 1, direct, null, 1, null, draft, null, 1, null, 2018-07-26 10:56:05.683, 2018-07-26 11:55:35, WH/IN/00002, t, null, null, none, f, null, null, null)
" while evaluating
u'action_picking_create()'`

Comment: How did you add `designation2` ?

Comment: 'designation2': fields.char(string="Designation"),

Comment: As defined in your comment the column is can be NULL, maybe you provide the wrong code or there is duplication in the code that define `designation2` in more then one place.

Comment: I have found the problem and resolve it then i tried your code and it shows nothing as usual

Comment: This code is working and you should see the reference to 'purchase.ordrer' if you add it in the XML view

Comment: How can i see it ?

Comment: You asked for it in your comment.now you can use `designation2 = fields.Char(related='purchase_id.name')`